# Why does an array of user defined type have to call the default constructor thereof?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Please consider the following example

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;    
    Foo(int i):bar(i){cout << "real ctor\n";}   
    Foo(){cout << "default ctor\n";}
};

int main()
{   
    Foo fooArr[3];//default ctor called 3 times 
    for(int i=0;i!=3;++i)cout << fooArr[i].bar << endl;//bare memory junk
    cout << endl;

    vector<Foo> fooVec;
    for(int i=0;i!=3;++i){
        fooVec.push_back(Foo(i));     //only real ctor called
        cout << fooVec[i].bar << endl;//real thing 
    }
    cout << endl;

    int iArr[3];
    for(int i=0;i!=3;++i)cout << iArr[i] << endl;//bare memory junk
}
```

I don't want any user of `Foo` to call its default constructor, because it's not in my design. But I'd like my users to be able to use an array of `Foo`, to support that, I was forced to provide a pointless and confusing Foo::Foo(). I just don't understand why does the C++ standard force programmers to do such a thing. What is the rationale behind it? Why the inconsistency? Could any of you smart guys who get this explain it to me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could always make an array of smart pointers.

Comment: My class is a POD, which is smaller than 4 bytes, smart pointers would be overkilling for that.

Comment: Your class is not a POD because it has user declared constructors.

Comment: It seems that the C++11 does allow defining constructor for a POD, however, that's not the point, what's important is that my class is very lightweight, without virtual functions and efficiently copyable, I just don't want to expose a meaningless default construstor for it.

Comment: You are asking *why* the default constructor gets called. Whether you want it to be called or not changes nothing. If you don't want a default constructor, then you need a different approach.

Comment: `Foo() = default;` It takes one line. Why is it such a problem?

Comment: @juanchopanza - No, I'm neither asking why they get called, nor asking for some workaround,  I'm asking why there is such a rule, I just don't understand the rationale.

Comment: The constructor is not a virtual function, so I don't see the problem there. Also, if you want it efficient, just use a typedef from int to Foo.

Comment: Which rule are you referring to? That a default constructed fixed size array is full of default constructed elements? That default constructing a user defined type involves a call to a default constructor?

Comment: @juanchopanza The rule is defining an array of primitive type doesn't initialize it automatically with default value, i.e. call default constructors of primitive types (`int arr[3]` doesn't mean `int arr[] = {int(),int(),int()}`) , only an array of user defined type compel automatic calling of the default ctor.

Comment: It has to call **some** constructor because it calls the destructor for every object in the array when it goes out of scope. If it didn't, you would have had to create **and** free the objects in the array explicitly. Primitive types don't have destructors, so this is not an issue for them.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your answers help a lot! C++ is such a convoluted language that sometimes I hate its guts ;) Every time I try to squeeze the memory comsumption or try to push the performance I end up hitting a wall. Vector is easy to use yet it consumes 4 more bytes, and bloats the binary a little bit, array is good for memory yet it forces me to define a extra ctor. I just can not win with it!

Comment: Bear in mind that having constructors or other methods does not affect the size of the object. And you are not forced to define an *extra* constructor. You are forced to declare and define the constructor that the compiler would have generated had you not declared and defined `Foo(int)`.

Comment: But the function call overhead is unavoidable.

Comment: It isn't completely unavoidable. The compiler is allowed to make all kinds of optimizations. The best approach is to profile first, before trying to outsmart the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make arrays of `Foo` even if it doesn't have a default constructor. It's just that the elements **have to** be constructed when you declare the array. So you can do this:

```
Foo fooArr[] = { Foo( 1 ), Foo( 2 ), Foo( 3 ) };
```

The alternative is to use a a dynamic array (your `vector<Foo>` example, which is probably best) or an array of pointers to `Foo` (like `shared_ptr<Foo> arrFoo[3]`)

```
shared_ptr<Foo> arrFoo[3];
arrFoo[2].reset( new Foo(3) );
```

A final note about `vector<Foo>`: since the size of the array is known in advance, you can improve performance by reserving enough space in the vector for all future `Foo`s:

```
vector<Foo> arrFoo;
arrFoo.reserve( 3 );

for( int i = 0; i<3; ++i )
    arrFoo.push_back( Foo( i ) );
```

EDIT: Your question was why do you have to have a default constructor to make a static array of the type. I thought the answer was clear but I'll try to explain it.

`Foo bar1; Foo bar2;` creates two objects using the default constructor, since no arguments were provided.

`Foo bar[2];` is essentially the same thing. It declares two objects that need to be constructed. There is no way to declare an object without constructing it - that's the very point of declaring it in the first place.

**A static array in C++ is just a bunch of objects placed contiguously memory. It's not a separate object.**

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm aware of the solution you provided, but they're not the anwser for my question, thanks though

Comment: Your edit does make sense, but I don't consider a static array to be objects placed consecutively together, I regard an array just as a chunk of memory(length x sizeof(type)) with type checking as a bonus . I only need the chunk of mem to be allocated, I don't need it to be manipulated before I actually use it. That's why I raised this question.

Comment: Then it's an array of `char` you're after, not an array of `Foo`. The type of the array is exactly the reason it's not just a chunk of memory - it has objects in it. You **can** construct an object in a pre-allocated memory chunk. That's exactly what `vector` does - check out _placement new_.

Comment: @Alex: calls to `reserve` are mostly useless in general given that `push_back` is amortized O(1).

Comment: `std::vector`'s reallocation algorithm is very efficient, that's true. Still, if you know the approximate size in advance, you gain some speed and lose nothing by using it.

Answer (score 3):

The rationale is that the array is full of default constructed elements, so the type of the elements must be default constructible. If you initialized the array with some values, the default construction wouldn't be required:

```
Foo fooArr1[3]; // full of default constructed Foos
Foo fooArr[3] = {1,2,3}; // default constructor not required. Foo(int) called.
```

Note that the second line in the code example uses the implicit conversion from `int` to `Foo` provided by the implicit `Foo(int)` converting constructor.

The reason you have to provide your own default constructor is that you have declared one constructor, which disables the automatic generation of the default constructor. The rationale behind this is that if you need to provide some constructor, it is likely that you also want to do something special in the default constructor.

If you really are worried about user provided constructors, then you can make your class a real aggregate and use aggregate initialization:

```
struct Foo
{
  // no user declared constructors
  int foo;
};

int main()
{   
    Foo fooArr1[3]; // OK
    Foo fooArr[3] = { {1}, {2}, {3} }; // aggregate construction 
}
```

In C++11 you can enable the compiler generated default constructor using `default`:

```
Foo()=default;
```

Comment: Yes, they're always required, unless I initialize it with an aggregate list: `Foo fooArr[] = {Foo(1),Foo(2),...,};` But what I want is to set the elements of the array dynamically, namely one by one.

Comment: @Need4Steed you are asking about the rationale behind this, which is what this answer addresses. If you want to add non-default constructed instances to a collection, the actual solution depends on the details of your case. Also, whether you have C++11 support or not might make a difference too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose: either not defining a default constructor, and therefore, you can't declare an array of `Foo`. Or declaring a default constructor (empty even) and can declare an array of `Foo`.

If you have dealt before with OOP languages such as C# or Java, and you have a `class Foo` and `Foo[] arr`, then you don't have to declare default constructor, because the array in these languages carries only references (addresses) to objects. The array itself is an object, so `arr` when created will == `null`. When using `arr = new Foo[3];` then we make a new object of array that contains 3 references: `arr == { null, null, null }`. Then you assign an object to each reference: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) arr[i] = new Foo(i);`.

However, C++ is different because the arrays carry the object itself rather than a reference to it. So, when carrying the object itself, it must have no-parameter constructor to be called with each object. (i.e. in C++: `Foo arr[3];` then `arr = { objectOfFoo, objectOfFoo, objectOfFoo }`

A solution to your problem may found by decalring an array of pointers:

```
Foo * arr[10] = { 0 }; // arr = { NULL, NULL, NULL, ... , NULL }
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) arr[i] = new Foo(3); // you don't have to declare default constructor

// some using of array
// C++ doesn't have a garbage collector
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) delete arr[i];
```

Comment: C# does have value types(structs), they can be truely held in an array just like what C++ does, and C# doesn't force you to define a default constructor, the memory chunk allocated for the array will be automatically zeroed out. It's actually not allowed to define a constuctor with on params for a struct type.

Comment: @Need4Steed So I was talking about classes, not structs

Comment: In c++ `struct` and `class` are equivalent in this context.